# Missing Image After Hosting in 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, crud, laravel-8

I have a **simple CRUD project with laravel**. everything runs smoothly on the local server, but after I try hosting at **000webhosting** all the images on my project don't appear ... maybe it's in the url.

This is how the web looks after hosting:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yETu.png)

this my code
1:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ Storage::url('public/brands/cb_indonesia.png') }}">
```

2:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="{{ Storage::url('public/brands/cb_indonesia.png') }}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" loading="lazy">
            Lestari Nusantara
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item mx-1">
                    <a href="{{ route('blog.create') }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-1">
                    <a href="https://github.com/rahmannurhidayat022" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

3:

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach ($blogs ?? '' as $blog)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card my-2 shadow-sm">
                    <img src="{{ Storage::url('public/blogs/').$blog->image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $blog->image }}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ $blog->title }}</h5>
                        {!! $blog->content !!}
                        <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin ?');" action="{{ route('blog.destroy', $blog->id) }}" method="POST">
                            <a href="{{ route('blog.edit', $blog->id) }}" class="btn my-1 btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="submit" class="btn my-1 btn-block btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Of course, I have run the command [ php artisan storage:link ] ... and the results are running normally ... but after hosting everything has changed

Comment: You need to run php artisan storage:link command.

Comment: Of course, I have run the command ... and the results are running normally ... but after hosting everything has changed

Comment: Re-run the command in your hosting server via terminal.

Comment: but in free hosting can't access SSH :(...any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue is your image files aren't accessible in public so in laravel you want to run `php artisan storage:link` then you can access your images. More info check [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Of course, I have run the command ... and the results are running normally ... but after hosting everything has changed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are saying that you can't access the terminal on your hosting plan.
Here's a programmatical solution, create a web route inside routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Then visit that link using your web browser `yourdomain.com/link`.
If it didn't work try to find if there's a default storage folder inside the `/home/public_html` and delete it, then re-try again.

Another solution:

```
Route::get('/link', function () {        
   $target = '/home/public_html/storage/app/public';
   $shortcut = '/home/public_html/public/storage';
   symlink($target, $shortcut);
});
```

Make any required change to the $target variable and the $shortcut upon your files structure.

Comment: i try `Route::get('/link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
` and this result `ParseError
syntax error, unexpected ')' `

Comment: This is a syntax error, track the error at which file and line.. you have an additional ')' symbol.. find and delete it. The error is not related to the above code itself. @rahman022